# Wrong auto deduction c++14

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

Im having a strange behavior with 'auto' return type function. Anyone Knows why the second function call is returning a int instead of double?

Compiler Version: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

double operator+(const int& a,const std::string& b){
    return 3.4;
}
auto f(){
    return 3.4;
}
auto sum(auto a, auto b){
    return a + b;
}

int main(){
    std::cout<< sum(1.0, std::string("hello")) <<std::endl;
    std::cout<< sum(1, std::string("hello")) <<std::endl;
    std::cout<< f() << std::endl;
}
//3.4
//3
//3.4
```

Comment: cannot reproduce https://wandbox.org/permlink/QL7RutBlmreB1UkH

Comment: also auto parameter name is not standard C++ yet. Anyway with `template <class T, class U>` I get the same expected result.

Comment: And I can reproduce https://onlinegdb.com/HkfYI4Lj7

Comment: Works for me. You sure this code reproduces the issue? Can you provide compiler versions?

Comment: ISO c++ does not allow auto parameters. Try compiling with `-pedantic`. You can, however, use a lambda `static auto sum = [](auto a, auto b) { return a + b; };`

Comment: Even the following: `auto sum(auto a) { return 3.4; } int main() { cout << sum(0); }` prints just 3.

Comment: it's most likely a compiler bug, so please state your compiler version or we are just wasting time.

Comment: @KamilCuk onlinegdb is such bs. I cannot see compiler version, I cannot edit the compiler arguments

Comment: Does not compile for me using C++14.

Answer (score 2):

First of all auto function parameter is not standard C++. It's a gcc extension anticipating some work of the standard committee. At one point there was talk to allow this syntax with the introduction of concepts. I don't know if that is still the case.

As to the strange behavior it looks like it's just a compiler bug fixed somewhere between gcc 5.5.0 and gcc 6.1.0